# How to test AWS S3 get object method ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using aws sdk for ruby to retrieve an object from a bucket then read it. My code is something like:

```
def import_from_s3 

  #initiate the client
  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new({
      region:            region,
      access_key_id:     key_id,
      secret_access_key: secret
  })

  #Get the object
  resp = s3.get_object(bucket: bucket, key: key)
end
```

My question is how do I test this method without mocking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to (and you shouldn't even try) to test `#get_object`. That is not implemented by your code and you should assume it has been tested and it works. As for you method `#import_from_s3`, you have two options. You either don't test it since it is just a thin wrapper around `#get_object`; or you can make assertions/expectations on its return value.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation on how to go about it.

[Stubbing the aws client response](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html)

I used the default stub and it worked just fine.

`Aws.config[:s3] = {stub_responses: {get_object: {body: StringIO.new("XYZ")}}}`